# Matrices admit a QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I just wanted to ask which matrices admit a QR decomposition. I think that all matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with $m \ge n$ admit a QR decomp. Are these the only ones that have a QR decomp, or does it also work for $m <n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QR decomposition works for any matrices of any size. It is essentially just a [Gram–Schmidt orthogonalization process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) applied to rows of a matrix, which can be surely applied to any set of vectors.